# OleDbDataAdapter does not insert Datatable in access table

Tags: c#, oledbdataadapter

I have  record in sql server table . I am filling all record in DataTable from sql server and after i want to insert all record in access table. But no data inserting and no error occured on inserting time. Please provide need help

```
public bool SalesGenExistingCustomer_Insert_InAccessDB(DataTable DT)
    {

       bool flag = true;
       int ii = DT.Rows.Count;
        try
        {
            string SQL = "SELECT top 1 * FROM GenExistingcustomers";
            string INSERT = "INSERT INTO GenExistingcustomers([CustomerId],[CompanyName],[BillingAddress],[City],[State],[Zip],[Phone],[Email])" +
                            " VALUES (@CustomerId,@CompanyName,@BillingAddress,@City,@State,@Zip,@Phone,@Email)";

            OleDbConnection OleConn = new OleDbConnection(ConnString);
            OleDbDataAdapter OleAdp = new OleDbDataAdapter(SQL, OleConn);
            OleAdp.InsertCommand = new OleDbCommand(INSERT);
            OleAdp.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@CustomerId", OleDbType.LongVarChar, 1008, "CustomerId");
            OleAdp.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@CompanyName", OleDbType.LongVarChar, 1008, "CompanyName");
            OleAdp.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@BillingAddress", OleDbType.LongVarChar, 1008, "BillingAddress");
            OleAdp.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@City", OleDbType.LongVarChar, 1008, "City");
            OleAdp.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@State", OleDbType.LongVarChar, 1008, "States");
            OleAdp.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Zip", OleDbType.LongVarChar, 4000, "Zip");
            OleAdp.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Phone", OleDbType.LongVarChar, 1008, "Phone");
            OleAdp.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Email", OleDbType.LongVarChar, 1008, "Email");

            OleAdp.InsertCommand.Connection = OleConn;
            OleAdp.InsertCommand.Connection.Open();
            int i = OleAdp.Update(DT);
            OleAdp.InsertCommand.Connection.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogFile(ex.ToString());
            flag = false;
        }
        string ssss = DT.Rows[1][4].ToString();
        return flag;

    }
```

if you add one row like as - 
`DataRow dr;
           dr = DT.NewRow();
           dr[0] = "1";
           dr[1] = "AAAA";
           dr[2] = "3";
           dr[3] = "4";
           dr[4] = "5";
           dr[5] = "6";
           dr[6] = "7";
           dr[7] = "8";
           dr[8] = "9";
           DT.Rows.Add(dr);`
then it's  inserting one record but leaving another record.

Answer (score 0):

The rows in your data table must have the correct state to be inserted in a database by the data adapter (see [RowState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.rowstate(v=vs.80).aspx) property). The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171933(v=vs.90).aspx) says:

"*The adapter's Update method will update a single data table and execute the correct command (INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE) based on the RowState of each data row in the table.*"

In your case rows should be in `Added` state. It looks like that they aren't. Probably because [AcceptChanges](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.acceptchanges(v=vs.110).aspx) method was called. You can force the `Added` state by calling [DataRow.SetAdded](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.setadded(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

Comment: Hello, can you correct my code? I think this error occured by existing data which data i am loading from sql server table.

Comment: thanks of reply. I think error occurred by my existing data which i am loading from sql server table. my code is tested. I want to insert bulk record in access db. I check datatype is correct of DataTable and access Table. Can you check my code by filling data from sql server with same structure or different structure and  provide correct way. Same method i am using by odata services.I am filling record in list using odata services and then filling all data in DataTable from linq and then inserting succesfully. please help.

Comment: Did you try to use DataRow.SetAdded method suggested in my answer?

Comment: I am not inserting a record on DataTable. I have 1000 records in  sql server table whose data i am filling in DataTable.I do not need to insert row by DataRow.This is a testing process for finding error.Please suggest.

Comment: This is method of bulk inserting which 100% tested. Ok you can try. You add record more than one into DataTable and create table in access with same structure and try to insert. Problem is sql server table which  is not inserting and no any error occured